# Identify screw and dowel on this cabinet door

Tags: screws, hinges

[image: screw]
[image: dowel]

What are these? Screw has two positions: fixed and loose. I can only switch between them but I cannot unscrew.

Comment: that is a particular brand of a hinge ... the screws are included in the package with the hinge .... the screws attach the hinge to the cabinet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supposed to unscrew.
Loose means you can push the whole plastic plug into the hole.
Fixed makes the plastic plug expand to grip.
This functionality depends on having exactly the right size hole.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. It is the first time I encountered this type of hinge and screws.

Answer (score 0):

This type of hinge has incorporated several adjustments screws. These screws are for adjustment not for support. Many You-Tube videos will show how to install. It is known among other things as a European style cabinet door hinge.